# declaring global perl subroutines or global aliases

Tags: perl, oop, object, global

my question is, HOPEFULLY simple.

In Perl, how does one create a global scoped subroutine accessible to all objects thereafter?

```
sub throw
{
    die(shift);
}
```

Seems to work in global scope, but is not accessible to packages afterwards. I would like to avoid doing something of the sort of declaring that in every object in my application stack.

Side solution: How does one create an alias to a global keyword like die?

**Please note: I do not really care if doing something like this is considered best practice. Although they perform the same function in Perl, die is not throw, and throw is not die. The following syntax does not follow the OOP principles that I am trying to follow:**

```
die new Exception($message);
```

**However logically similar, for the purpose of throwing exceptions, I would prefer the syntax of:**

```
throw new Exception($message);
```

Many thanks to the stackoverflow community!

Comment: Please do not write `new Classname`. In Perl, `new` is just the name of a method, not a keyword, and it can confuse the interpreter. Instead, use `Exception->new($message)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `throw` to the `UNIVERSAL` package (which isn't a good practice).

Note that your `throw` ignores the message and displays just the class name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package UNIVERSAL;

    sub throw { die shift }
}

{   package MyClass;

    sub new { bless {}, shift }
}

my $c = 'MyClass'->new;
$c->throw('Ouch!');
```

See [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny).

Comment: Very interesting! I love the idea! It definitely centralizes it. I assume that there is no way to do just that in a means that allows me to use the syntax "throw new someObj()" by chance?

BTW, I was looking for how to do just this earlier. Perldocs is a bit vague sometimes.

Comment: Another note, I guess i'll add it above. My intention is to throw references to blessed exception objects. Hopefully in doing so I can store all kinds of useful information in them such as a stack trace. Thanks again!

Comment: @steve: `die` can throw exception objects.

Comment: I am aware. However, I do not like the syntax "die new Exception()" -- as stated above.

Comment: If there is no way to create an alias to a global perl function in global context, then this is the correct answer. Can you think of a way?

Comment: The normal way would be to create a module `MyThrow` that exports `throw` and `use` it from other modules/scripts.

Answer (score 1):

What about a paradigm such as this, which would solve both your issues at once?

```
package Exception;

sub throw {
  my $message = shift;
  die Exception->new($message);
}

sub new {
  # whatever
}

...
```

And then in any package you can use it thusly:

```
package SomeClass;

sub do_something {
  ...
  if ($error) {
    Exception->throw($message);
  }
}
```